# How would i write search and delete methods in `Organisation` class in current scenario

Tags: c#

I have a list of customers and branches in `Organisation` class and list of associations in the `Branch` class. Now the problem is that I made a method in organisation class to search and delete customer but i couldn't find out how to achieve my desired results.

Organization:

```
class Organization
{

    public static List<Branch> branches = new List<Branch>();

    public static List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

    Branch Branch1 = new Branch(new Guid(), "ABC", "XYZ", "5334");
    Branch Branch2 = new Branch(new Guid(), "ABC", "XYZ", "4584");
    Branch Branch3 = new Branch(new Guid(), "ABC", "XYZ", "2354");

    public void AddBranch()
    {
           //ADD NEW BRANCH*/
    }
    public void DisplayBranches()
    {
        // DISPLAY BRANCHES*/
    }
    public void AddCustomer()
    {
        //ADD NEW CUSTOMER AND SEND CUSTOMER ID TO ASSOCIATION LIST*/
    }

    public void SearchCustomer()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the Telno of the Customer to find its Information: ");
        var CtelNo = Console.ReadLine();

        foreach (var Citem in customers)
        {
            if (Citem.CustomerEmail == CtelNo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nCustomer ID:{0}\nCustomer Name:{1}\nCustomer Address:{2}\nCustomer Telno.:{3}\nCustomer Email:{4}\n", Citem.CustomerID, Citem.CustomerName, Citem.CustomerAddress, Citem.CustomerTelNo, Citem.CustomerEmail);

                foreach (Branch Bitem in branches)
                {
                   // How do i display associated branch */
                  //
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void DeleteCustomer()
    {
        //First remove all associaitons*/
        //Then remmove the desired customer*/
    }
}
```

Branch:

```
class Branch
{
    public Guid BranchID { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public string BranchAddress { get; set; }
    public string BranchTelNo { get; set; }

    public List<Association> Associations = new List<Association>();

    public Branch(Guid branchID, string branchName, string branchAddress, string branchTelNo)
    {
        BranchID = Guid.NewGuid();
        BranchName = branchName;
        BranchAddress = branchAddress;
        BranchTelNo = branchTelNo;
    }

    public void AddCustomerAssociation(Guid CustomerID)
    {

        Association association = new Association(CustomerID, this.BranchID);
        Associations.Add(association);

    }
}
```

Customer:

```
class Customer
{
    public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    public string CustomerTelNo { get; set; }

}

public class Association
{

    public Guid CID { get; set; }
    public Guid BID { get; set; }

    public Association(Guid cID, Guid bID)
    {
        CID = cID;
        BID = bID;
    }
} //
```

Comment: First you need to add customers in `List<Customer>` and then remove them with `Remove` method.

Comment: that is not the problem. its just how to show associated branches with the specific customer.

Comment: With related data I suggest  you to use lazy loading from EntityFramework.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something here, you basically have one-to-many relations you don't need the `Association` in the middle so the structure could be simpler:

```
class Customer
class Branch: List<Customer>
class Organization: List<Branch>
```

this would make your like life a whole lot easier..
you can then nest a couple of foreach loops that will do what you're after quite easily.

Comment: Well its many to many relation , branch can have many customer and customer can go to many branches. I Understood what you are trying to say and I can achieve my purpose easily the way you said it. But i want to achieve my result in a current scenario. It would be really helpful If you can give me any advice in a current scenario.

Comment: please see below another possible solution

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give some another approach on how to establish the relationships between customers and branches with double-sided IEnumerables:

customer class:

```
public class Customer
    {
        public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
        public string CustomerTelNo { get; set; }


        private readonly IList<Branch> _branches = new List<Branch>();
        public IEnumerable<Branch> Branches 
        {
            get { return _branches; }
        }

        // internal method to add branch to customer. will be called in the public method on branch's side
        internal void AddBranch(Branch branch) 
        {
            if (!_branches.Contains(branch)) _branches.Add(branch);
        }

        public Customer(string customername, string customeraddress, string customeremail, string customertelno) 
        {
            CustomerID = Guid.NewGuid();
            this.CustomerName = customername;
            this.CustomerAddress = customeraddress;
            this.CustomerEmail = customeremail;
            this.CustomerTelNo = customertelno;
        }

    }
```

Branch class:

```
 public class Branch 
    {
        public Guid BranchID { get; set; }
        public string BranchName { get; set; }
        public string BranchAddress { get; set; }
        public string BranchTelNo { get; set; }

        private readonly IList<Customer> _customers = new List<Customer>();
        public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers
        {
            get { return _customers; }
        }

        // add two-sided relation. the customer is added to the branch but the branch is add to the customer too
        // IMPORTANT: the relation can be added on one side of the relationship ONLY. 
        // I chose to add customers to branch, but it can be done the other way around
        public void AddCustomer(Customer customer) 
        {
            if (_customers.Contains(customer)) return;
            _customers.Add(customer);
            customer.AddBranch(this); // internal method is being called and branch is added to customer

        }

        public Branch(string branchname, string branchaddress, string branchtelno) 
        {
            this.BranchID = Guid.NewGuid();
            this.BranchName = branchname;
            this.BranchAddress = branchaddress;
            this.BranchTelNo = branchtelno;
        }

    }
```

And eventually, the Organization class (or whatever name you'd like to call it) which holds methods for add customers to branches (or vice versa, whatever works for you..) and to look up customers:

```
  public class Organization 
        {
            // add cutmoer to the branch
            public void AddCustomers(Branch branch, Customer customer) 
            {
                branch.AddCustomer(customer);

            }


            // search through List of branches for customer name. upon finding, print the customer and the branch details            
            public void SearchCustomer(string customername,IEnumerable<Branch> branches) 
            {


                foreach (var branch in branches)
                {
                    foreach (var customer in branch.Customers)
                    {

                        if (customername == customer.CustomerName) 
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("The customer you looked up:" + customername + "  " + customer.CustomerEmail + "  " + customer.CustomerTelNo);
                            Console.WriteLine("is a customer in branch:");
                            Console.WriteLine(branch.BranchName + "  " + branch.BranchAddress);


                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

And last but not least, the implementation:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // add some customer
    Customer john = new Customer("John", "1111 John Street", "john@gmail.com", "444-5555555");
    Customer johana = new Customer("johana", "2222 johana Street", "johana@gmail.com", "666-7777777");
    Customer johnny = new Customer("johnny", "3333 johnny Street", "johnny@gmail.com", "888-9999999");

    // add some branches
    Branch branch1 = new Branch("ABC", "XYZ", "5334");
    Branch branch2 = new Branch("DEF", "VDF", "6789");

    // instantiate the Organization class and attach customers to branches
    Organization org = new Organization();
    org.AddCustomers(branch1, john);
    org.AddCustomers(branch1, johana);

    // wrap all the branches in a list and...
    List<Branch> AllTheBranches = new List<Branch>();
    AllTheBranches.Add(branch1);
    AllTheBranches.Add(branch2);

    // have fun looking up customers. 
    // provide customer's name and get all the detail on both the customer and his branch
    org.SearchCustomer("John", AllTheBranches);

    Console.Read();



}
```

the output:

```
The customer you looked up:John  john@gmail.com  444-5555555
is a customer in branch:
ABC  XYZ
```

You could as well implement another method of reverse search, .i.e branches in list of customers in the exact same way:

```
SearchBranch(string branchName, List<Customer>)
```